# Pass associative array as bash arguments to a python/pytest script

Tags: python-3.x, bash, pytest, git-bash

I have declared an associative array in main_script.sh(bash version 4.4.19(2)) as follows:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    declare -A hash_map
    hash_map["MOCK_KEY"]="99999"

    pytest --name abc --strict_mode True --hash_details hash_map ./test_file.py;
```

I have a conftest.py file as follows:

```
    parser.addoption("--hash_details", action="store", default="default name")
    parser.addoption("--format_name", action="store", default="default name")
    parser.addoption("--strict_mode", action="store", default="default name")
```

Contents of test_file.py:

```
    @pytest.fixture()
    def name(pytestconfig):
        return pytestconfig.getoption("name")

    @pytest.fixture()
    def strict_mode(pytestconfig):
        return pytestconfig.getoption("strict_mode")

    @pytest.fixture()
    def trace_details(pytestconfig):
        return pytestconfig.getoption("hash_details")

    def test_function(name, strict_mode, hash_details):
        print("hash_details", hash_details)
```

When I print hash_details in test_file.py, I expected a dictionary with the key-value defined in the bash script but I got the string "hash_map". How can I retrieve the hash_map dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with `pytest` but Bash cannot send objects to Python.

The arguments from Bash can only be parsed as strings. You need to format the strings sent to Python either using [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or some other format yourself that Python/you can parse/convert into the type you are looking for.

You can use [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) to parse the arguments sent to your python script from BASH.

Perhaps pytest already has support for this argument handling in some way, in which case you need to explore the documentation for [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html)

Comment: Although from my cursory glance `pytest` does not have support for argument parsing from bash.